# How to draw circles or Line in UrhoSharp

Tags: xamarin, urhosharp

am using urhosharp game engine from xamarim to develop a cross-platform game .... it was really good choice and compatible with WPF but I did not know how to draw shapes , I went through the guide and documentation and did not find a way maybe to draw circles,Rounded Shapes,annulus or any geometric type anyone knows or could help me . I would be very grateful .

**Thanks in advance**

I tried this piece of code but no circle appeared in the screen:

```
DebugRenderer debug = new DebugRenderer();
debug.AddCircle(new Vector3(50,50,0),new Vector3(100,25,0),50,Color.Magenta,2 ,true  );

       for (int i = 0; i < 512; ++i)
                {
                    var start = new Vector3(i, 0, 0);
                    var end = new Vector3(i, 100, 0);

                    debug.AddLine(start, end, Color.White, false);
                    debug.AddCircle(start, end, 50f, Color.Red, i, false);
                }

    scene.AddComponent(debug);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just want to note that DebugRenderRender is intended for debugging purposes. If you want to make DebugRenderer work you will need to subscribe to PostRenderUpdate like this:

```
Engine.SubscribeToPostRenderUpdate(args => YourMethodHandler);
```

Usually you will do that in your setup. And then YourMethodHandler is like:

```
protected void YourMethodHandler()
{
    // this requires that you have already added a DebugRenderer
    // component in your scene object
    var debugRenderer = scene.GetComponent<DebugRenderer>();

    if (debugRenderer != null)
    {
        // do your drawing code here
        // to draw a rectangle for example:

        var upperBound = new Vector3(-4.0f, 2.0f, 0.0f);
        var lowerBound = new Vector3(4.0f, -2.0f, 0.0f);
        debugRenderer.AddBoundingBox(
            new BoundingBox(upperBound, lowerBound), 
            Color.White, 
            false);
    }
}
```

Comment: is using DebugRenderer the only way to draw primitives in 3d space?

Answer (score 1):

To be more precise, it works only when implemented like this:

```
var dr = app.Scene.GetOrCreateComponent<DebugRenderer>();
app.Engine.PostRenderUpdate += (arg4) => {
    app.Renderer.DrawDebugGeometry(false);
};
app.Renderer.BeginViewRender += (arg5) => {
    dr.AddBoundingBox(new BoundingBox(-1000, 1000), Color.Blue);
    dr.LineAntiAlias = true;
    dr.AddTriangle(new Vector3(2,0,0), new Vector3(2,1,0), new Vector3(2,0,1), Color.Magenta, false);
    dr.AddCircle(new Vector3(2,0,0), new Vector3(1,1,1), 5.0f, Color.Red);
};
```